# Sound stopped working after upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, sound

My notebook is a Dell Inspiron 15 Gaming. My Ubuntu's version is xenial.

After upgrading from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04; the computer could not detect the sound card anymore... Also, alsamixer was not working neither...

I tried to do somethings: reinstall alsa utils; installed some drivers manually (oem-audio-hda-daily-Its-xenial-dkms).

Now the sound card is detected, the alsamixer works, when the computer starts it makes the initialization sound, but after I login there is no more sound...

When I open the sound configurations menu; there is nothing to choose as 'sound output', before, when the sound card was not detected, there was the option 'dummy output'.

I really don't know what to do anymore, it's the first time I am trying to use Linux in my PC, so I don't understand half of what people say in the forums where I am searching for an answer...

Comment: If you solved your problem yourself, please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) and accept your answer. Don’t put the answer in your question or the comments! I took the liberty to revert the edit that adds the answer to the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/374742/47852) to the [cross-posted question on Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/374182/47852):

> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/alsa-daily
> sudo apt update
> ```
>
> After updating alsa drivers, they will be reconfigured. I had the same problem, this solved it.
>
> ```
> sudo aptitude --purge reinstall linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils linux-image-`uname -r` linux-ubuntu-modules-`uname -r` libasound2
> ```
>
> This will restore and reconfigure all sound drivers in ubuntu 16.04 to their default state. You may look whether **proprietary drivers** are enabled then.
>
> As you said, you can try `sudo apt install --reinstall pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-x11` and logout. If I can start with "it makes the initialization sound" again, it sounds definitely like user-related error. Consider making another user account to test whether the problem persists...
>
> Another thing is, that your `pulseaudio` daemon may not start upon login.
> Check **System > Administration > BootUp Manager** to make sure the service is activated.
> The `/etc/int.d/pulseaudio` shell script should start the daemon, too.